# Выполнить код после загрузки всех картинок

Tags: javascript

Делаю простую 2d игрушку на js. Имеется массив спрайтов(массив объектов класса Sprite(Sprite наследуется от Image и есть возможность посмотреть поле complete и вызвать событие onload)), хочу чтобы выполнение цикла игры начиналось после загрузки всех спрайтов. Как можно это сделать? Было много костыльных идей, но никак не могу понять как ето можно нормально реализовать.

Answer (score 0):

Можно завести счетчик, взять массив картинок, начать циклом их загружать и при каждой загрузке считать +1. Когда счетчик дойдет до размера массива, значит всё загрузилось, можно запускать игру:

```js
onload_sprites(start_game);

function onload_sprites(callback) {
  let sprites = [
    "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
    "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
    "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
    "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
    "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
  ];
  
  let sprites_loaded = 0;
  
  sprites.forEach(function(sprite) {
    let img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      sprites_loaded++;
      call();
    };
    
    img.onerror = function() {
      sprites_loaded++;
      console.log(sprite, "не загрузился!");
      call();
    }
    img.src = sprite;
  });
  
  function call() {
    if( sprites_loaded === sprites.length ) {
      callback();
    }
  }
}

function start_game() {
  console.log("Начали!");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но у меня вопрос был в том, чтобы загрузить все картинки, потом выполнять код, а не просто проверить на загрузку каждый элемент.

Comment: @huffy Оно и загружает, а не просто проверяет... Это то же самое, что добавить теги img в body и ждать их полной загрузки: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```js
let sprites = [
  "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
  "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
  "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
  "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
  "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
];

(async () => {

  const allResources = await Promise.all(sprites.map(url => fetch(url)));
  console.log(allResources);

})();
```